# Can I downgrade my Nexus One from Android 2.3.6 (Gingerbread) to Android 2.2 (Froyo)?

Tags: rom-flashing, 2.3-gingerbread, 2.2-froyo, nexus-one, downgrade

So I was wondering whether it's possible to downgrade my old Nexus One which is currently on gingerbread back to Froyo. If so, how do I go about this? I don't know much about downgrading on Android, but I think I have to root the device first and then flash a stock ROM. If that's the case, where could I find Android 2.2 ROM for my Nexus One? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nexus One was a develope device that can be unlocked easily, therefore you can install any matching ROM. So theoretically this is possible however practically it will be very hard to find OS images to such an old device. I would assume that you will find many many dead links. BTW why Domain want to install Android 2.2? 2.3 is as outdated as 2.2 more or less no app will support any OS of that age anymore.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the help man. I want to go back to Froyo because it feels smoother and overall looks better than gingerbread in my opinion. It's true that many apps don't support it nowadays, but I don't really plan on using it for daily tasks, I have a Samsung a10e from two years ago as my daily driver. I also have another question, do I have to root my nexus in order to install the ROM or can I just unlock the boot loader and flash?

Comment: Just unlock the bootloader. Please keep in mind that such old systems are heavily insecure. Never ever connect it to any network.